# How to create AWS New-Scprovisionedproduct through powershell

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell

I'm trying to create a provisioned product in service catalog by using PowerShell.

```
cmdlet $newProduct = New-SCProvisionedProduct -ProvisionedProductName $product_name  -ProductId $product_id  
-ProvisioningArtifactId $artifact_id  -ProvisioningParameter @( @{key="Server_size";value="$server.serversize"},{key= "Key_pair",value="demo_key"} )
```

But I don't know how to pass multiple values in provisioning parameter it showing some error

```
New-SCProvisionedProduct : Cannot bind parameter 'ProvisioningParameter'. 
Cannot convert the "[" value of type "System.String" to type 
"Amazon.ServiceCatalog.Model.ProvisioningParameter".
At line:1 char:162
+ ... -ProvisioningArtifactId $artifact_id -ProvisioningParameter [ {key="S ...
+                                                                 ~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [New-SCProvisionedProduct], 
    ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Amazon.PowerShell 
   .Cmdlets.SC.NewSCProvisionedProductCmdlet
```

Could anyone help me with the AWS Powershell command to pass multiple values in provisioning parameter (or) help to sort this error

Comment: You don't need quotes around the value if you are passing in a variable. Try the following instead `@{key="Server_size";value=$server.serversize}`

Comment: I tried this but,still im not getting it $newProduct = New-SCProvisionedProduct     
-ProvisionedProductName $product_name  -ProductId $product_id  -ProvisioningArtifactId $artifact_id -ProvisioningParameter @( {key="Server_size";value=$server.serversize},{key="Key_pair";value:"demo_key"},{key:"CIDR_range";value:"0.0.0.0/0"})         Error: New-SCProvisionedProduct : Cannot bind parameter 'ProvisioningParameter'. Cannot convert  "key="Server_size";value=$server.serversize" value of type "System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock" to type 
"Amazon.ServiceCatalog.Model.ProvisioningParameter".

Comment: You are missing an `@` in front of `{key=key_pair`

Comment: Its working $Product = New-SCProvisionedProduct -ProvisionedProductName $product_name -ProductId $product_id  -ProvisioningArtifactId $artifact_id -ProvisioningParameter @( @{key="InstanceType";value=$server.serversize},@{key="KeyName";value="demo_key"},@{Key="SSHLocation";value="0.0.0.0/0"})